# Essential upper bound and essential supremum

Tags: measure-theory

Let  $f : [a , b] → R$  be a function from a closed bounded interval of  $R$ into $R$. And let  $f$   is essentially bounded from above i.e, it has an essential upper bound.

Now consider the following set:

$A$ =  {$ p \in R │p$  is an essential upper bound of  $f$  }

Clearly the set $A$ is a nonempty subset of $R$ as $f$  is essentially bounded from above.

I know that by definition essential supremum of  $f$  is equal to the infimum of  the set $A$.
But according to g.l.b (greatest lower bound) property the nonempty set $A$ will have infimum (g.l.b) if it is bounded from below. Thus my question is how to show that the set $A$ is bounded from below. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $A$ is not bounded below.Then there exist $(p_n) \subset A$ such that $p_n \to -\infty$. But $f\leq p_n$ a.e for each $n$. This implies that $f =-\infty $ a.e. Hence $A$ must have  a lower bound.